# How to replace jar file in Spring Boot docker project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a Spring Boot docker project. Below is the `docker-compose.yaml` contents:

```
app:
  build: ./app
  container_name: app
  restart: always
  working_dir: /app
  volumes:
    - ./app/target/app-exe.jar:/app/app-exe.jar
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  entrypoint: java -jar /app/app-exe.jar
  depends_on:
    - mysql
```

I have run it using `docker-compose up -d`. Right now I need to replace this `app-exe.jar` jar file using the new one. All I can think right now is by first `docker-compose down` and then replace the jar file and do `docker-compose up -d` again. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sharing jars from host to container also is not a great idea, you should use dockerfile to build the jar and move it inside the container. Best would be to use a dockerfile which builds the jar and use `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Do you mean build jar inside container? I tried and no success and it's too complicated for me. This is easier. And it's working.

Comment: Then just go for `docker-compose up --force-recreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you just want to make sure you recreate your containers. You can use below command

```sh
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Comment: There is a mysql image inside that I didn't list here. How do I only force recreate this Spring Boot app?

Comment: `docker-compose up --force-recreate <servicename>`